# How do I create this complex user filter?

Tags: tableau-api

I have a list of initiatives (proposals) which have an originating team and impacting team.

For e.g.
[image]

There are leads for each of these teams and yes the impacted teams data is a continuous string of teams.

Originating team will be part of impacted teams too.

Given that there is a mapping between Originating teams and leads, I have created a user filter such that Leads only see the initiatives originating from their teams. That was pretty straightforward. User filter on Originating teams and mapped the users to the teams.

Now the ask is, they also want to see the initiatives that impact them.

For e.g. The Product lead also want to see the Initiative 2 where they are impacted.

How do I go about creating this complex user filter?

Comment: I would try using a custom sql query, and create a cartesian to simplify the filter requirement

Comment: Are you able to show how you have written the current filter? It may be a simple case of adding to that.